# Question about parabolic arch depth and width

Tags: functions

A bridge with a parabolic span with equation d=w^2/800-200, where the d is depth of the arch in metres.

a) Find the depth of the arch at a point 10m from its widest span.
b) Find the width across the span at a depth of 100 m.

I'm not sure if I'm meant to be substituting something into the equation or what direction to actually take to solve those two questions.

Answer (score 1):

Part b) is straightforward. Just substitute 100 for $d$ and solve for $w$.

Since no value is given for the widest span or for the depth at which it occurs, you will have to use symbolic values for those amounts and express the answer relative to those symbolic values.

Let $w_0$ and $d_0$ denote the widest span and the depth at which it occurs.

Then the depth $d$ at a width $w=w_0-10$ will be

\begin{eqnarray}
d&=&\frac{(w_0-10)^2}{800}-200\\
&=&\frac{w_0^2}{800}-200-\frac{20w_0-100}{800}\\
&=&d_0-\frac{w_0-5}{40}
\end{eqnarray}

So the depth at which the width is 10 meters narrower would be smaller by an amount $\dfrac{w_0-5}{40}$ meters.